# Why is drawing to the Android canvas not modifying my bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, android-canvas

Looking for help troubleshooting why the bitmap is not being modified by this drawing.  Have looked at numerous examples, and my code seems to match what is listed. What am I missing?

This is the relevant code (the class is constructed elsewhere, and the `drawSomething()` call is in an `onTouchEvent` handler). I've shortened the code for brevity:

```
class MyView extends View {

    Bitmap mBitmap;
    BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable;
    Canvas mCanvas;
    Paint mPaint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBitmap);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    public void drawSomething() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFF00FF00);  // This should "fill" the canvas
        int radius = 10;
        mCanvas.drawCircle(50, 50, radius, mPaint);     // This should draw a circle at (50, 50)

        int count=0;
        for (int i=0; i<mBitmap.getWidth(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<mBitmap.getHeight(); j++)
            {
                if (mBitmap.getPixel(i, j) > 0)
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            Log.v("MyApp", "Nothing was drawn!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `drawSomething()`?

Comment: Edited to explain usage. Thanks

Comment: If you are sure this code could replicate the problem, I think you should simply create a sample app and put on github, such that it would be easier for people to try it out.

Comment: Doesn't `getPixel` return a `Color` object? Is that comparable to `0`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int, int)

Comment: It's described as a Color but if you look closely, the returned data type is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  Turns out that the canvas drawing was working as expected (no surprise there).  There were two other issues.

I overlooked the signed-ness of a Java `int` datatype.  The `int` value `0xFF00FF00` evaluates less than 0.  This explains why the count in my troubleshooting code evaluated to 0.

I was not seeing any drawing in the bitmap because I was ultimately using the `draw` method of the `mBitmapDrawable` object to draw the bitmap to the screen.  After changing my code to use the `drawBitmap` method of the `Canvas` object, the mutable bitmap was properly drawn.  I speculate that the `BitmapDrawable` makes a copy of the provided bitmap in its constructor, and therefore I was not seeing the modifications I had made to the bitmap.